# Page stop being rendered without any errors

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having a problem with a specific page using PHP + Symfony 2. The page stop being rendered in a specific point, always when a twig template is included with `{% include %}` tag. Its only happening in production environment. I've turned on logs, but nothing is showed, even in PHP or apache log.

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: *this page* requires a login. do you have a demo account?

Comment: do you have error_reporting turned on `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set("display_errors", "on");`

Comment: SOrry, use "demo" "demo123" for login.

Comment: @Orangepill I've turned this errors reporting only in this action, inside the createAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Was one null object being called in a twig template, like `{{ object.element }}` where `object` does not exists. What was strange was that symfony didn't logged or showed the error.

Thank you all for support.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://hom.gorockbee.com/app_dev.php/create and you will se the error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)") in "FOSUserBundle:Security:login.html.twig".
>   500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime 1 linked Exception:
>   PDOException »

Comment: THis exception happened because you use 'dev' environment and this environment is using 'prod' settings. :/